# Brick wall uses 2 less bricks per level. How many bricks will there be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a brick wall that forms a rough triangle shape and at each level, the amount of bricks used is two bricks less than the previous layer. Is there a formula we can use to calculate the amount of bricks used in the wall, given the amount of bricks at the bottom and top levels?

Comment: Yes. Yes there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S = (a_1 + a_n)/2*(a_n-a_1 + 2)/2$

Sum of the elements of an arithmetic progression is $S = (a_1+a_n)*n/2$. In case you do not now what $n$ is equal to, you can use the following formula:
$S = (a_1 + a_n)/2*(a_n-a_1 + x)/x$, where $a_1$ is the first element, $a_n$ is the last element, $x$ is the "step", the number by which you increment each element of the progression in order to get its next element.

Comment: Are the two's in that equation constants or do they depend on the increment?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Make one identical wall right next to it, but upside-down. How many bricks are in each row of the two walls combined? How many bricks have you then used for those two walls?

Comment: `(z - a)*(z + a)`, right? `z` being the number of blocks on the bottom and `a` being the number on top.

Comment: @CalebBertrand There are $\frac{z-a}2$ rows, not $z-a$, since each row in the original wall has $2$ more bricks than the one above. And remember that this is the number of bricks in _two_ walls.

Answer (score 0):

You should first work through the problem using the hints given. Here is a solution for once you are done.

> Let's say the lower layer has $x$ bricks, and there are a total of $n$ layers. Then the top layer has $a:=x-2(n-1)$ bricks (you can check this is correct by plugging in something like $n=2,3$). Then build an identical wall, but upside down and place it next to the first one. The lower layer of the first wall had $x$ bricks, and the lower layer of the second wall has $a$ bricks. So the lower layer of the combined wall has $x+a$ bricks, and the same is true for all $n$ layers. So the total number of bricks in this combined wall is $(x+a)n=n(x+x-2(n-1))=n(2x-2n+2)$. The total amount of bricks in the original wall is then half of this, ie $n(x-n+1).$